# Send json to php through a form

Tags: php, javascript, json, forms

```
$('<form method="post" action="login/makeLogin"><input type="hidden" name="fbphoto" value="'+image +
                    '"><input type="hidden" name="fbname" value="'+response.first_name +'"><input type="hidden" name="fbemail" value="'+response.email +'"><input type="hidden" name="fbid" value="'+response.id+
                    '"><input type="hidden" name="fbsurname" value="'+response.last_name +'"><input type="hidden" name="fbfriends" value="'+json +'"></form>').appendTo('body')
```

I create this form dynamicly with javascript. But when I try to send this form to a php function, it returns false when I try to access the fbfriends property the rest values work fine. The value of fbfriends is a string containing json, which I get using:

```
var json=JSON.stringify(response.friends);
```

If I dont stringify the json I get a string [Object object] when retrieving values in the php function. How can I send json through a form.

Comment: you have answer to your question use `JSON.stringify` because otherwise the json is convert to string ising `toString` method

Comment: I get false when I use stringify

Comment: you can try to escape quotes `JSON.stringify(response.friends).replace(/"/g, '\\"');`

Comment: It work now but I have to &#34 to replace the quotes

Answer (score 1):

Your form only contains hidden items.  Why don't you post the response values through $.ajax directly?